# Throws SyntaxError while trying to run grunt build --env=devel --platform=android --crosswalk=false

Tags: gruntjs, cordova-plugins, cordova-android

This is the command I am trying to run to build the project with platforms and plugins installed

```
grunt build --env=devel --platform=android --crosswalk=false
```

It is throwing syntax error

When I run this I get

```
Running "build" task

Build Parameters
================
env       = devel
platform  = android
crosswalk = false

Running "cleanup:devel:android" (cleanup) task

Running "shell:remove_all_platforms" (shell) task
C:\Users\saius\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.13.0\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt-lib.js:64
const StringType = typeDefs.String?.type

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:18)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
at Object.<anonymous>
```

Note:
Node version: 12.13.0
NPM version: 6.12.0
Cordova version: ~12.0.1[New version released by the cordova-android]

It should build the project with platforms and plugins installed

Comment: Your Node version is way too old for that Cordova release.

Answer (score 0):

You should update Node version: 12.13.0 upper than 14.x
Here we had the same error and after update on 16.x it's gone